# Backbone Model : Ajax request in parse override

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a scenario where a `fetch()` call of a model will return data from which a property will need be passed to another API and return type from that API will be the actually required data.

```
var Issue = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'https://api.github.com/repos/ibrahim-islam/ibrahim-islam.github.io/issues',
    parse: function(response, options){
        var markdown = new Markdown({ text : response.body });
        markdown.fetch({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify( markdown.toJSON() ),
            success: function(data){
                response.body = data;
            }
        });
        return response;
    }
});

var Markdown = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        'text': '',
        'mode' : 'markdown'
    },
    url: 'https://api.github.com/markdown'
});
```

So, when an `Issue` will be fetched:

```
var issue = new Issue({id: 1});
issue.fetch().then(function(){
  //do stuff
});
```

It will have a property of `body` containing markdown syntax text which in turn I need to pass to another API and get the that response which will be passed down to view.

As can be seen from above, I tried overriding `parse` but its return type has to be an object and `fetch` will be `async` so what can I do here to make this work?

NOTE: I know aggregating the data in server and then receiving it will be best idea but that is not possible atm.

Comment: `JSON.stringify( markdown.toJSON() )` - that would be double encoding, are you sure you want that?

Comment: @Tomalak Only after that my request goes through. But I will try again. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the [sync method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) in your `Issue`  model to chain your requests.

```
var Issue = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'https://api.github.com/repos/ibrahim-islam/ibrahim-islam.github.io/issues',

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        if (method !== 'read')
            return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);

        // first request
        var xhr = Backbone.ajax({
            type: 'GET', 
            dataType: 'json',
            url: _.result(model, 'url')
        });

        // second request
        return xhr.then(function (resp1) {
            var markdown = new Markdown({text : resp1.body || 'body'});
            var data = markdown.toJSON();

            // the callback to fill your model, will call parse
            var success = options.success;

            return Backbone.ajax({
                url: _.result(markdown, 'url'),
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data
            }).then(function(resp2) {
                // sets the data you need from the response
                var resp = _.extend({}, resp1, {
                    body: resp2
                });

                // fills the model and triggers the sync event
                success(resp);

                // transformed value returned by the promise
                return resp;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The options hash passed to `Model.sync` contains the callbacks to `model.parse`, you can use it to set the attributes on your model when you're satisfied with your data.

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/puwueqe3/5/

Comment: This seems better than my suggestion. +1 from me.

Comment: @nikoshr I need both the main object and then the markdown parsed result so that I can replace the `body` property. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimislam/puwueqe3/2/

Comment: @lbrahim I somehow missed that the second request was returning HTML and not JSON. Updated

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to override the model's `fetch` to get this to work

Consider what the default fetch looks like:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = _.extend({parse: true}, options);
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    var serverAttrs = options.parse ? model.parse(resp, options) : resp;
    if (!model.set(serverAttrs, options)) return false;
    if (success) success.call(options.context, model, resp, options);
    model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
},
```

([github](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L587-L599))

That implementation would not support an async version of `model.parse`, but since you create a model class using `.extend` you can override this with your own implementation so lets look at what it does. It takes an `options` objects, creates a `success` callback and then delegates to `Backbone.Sync`.

It's that callback that calls `parse` and that's what needs to be made to support async.

The quickest, dirtiest way to do this is probably to just copy and modify the existing default fetch.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    fetch: function(options) {
      options = _.extend({parse: true}, options);
      var model = this;
      var success = options.success;
      options.success = function(resp) {

        function parser(resp, options, cb) {
           ...do your async request stuff and call cb with the result when done...
        }

        parser(resp, options, function(result) {
            if (!model.set(result, options)) return false;
            if (success) success.call(options.context, model, resp, options);
            model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
        });

      };
      wrapError(this, options);
      return this.sync('read', this, options);
    }

});
```

This is just an example of how you might try to solve this. I've not tested it and it might not work but I don't see any immediately obvious reasons why it shouldn't.